# Unable to create java virtual machine

Tags: java, windows, java-8, jvm

I am using Windows 10 64-bit. I have installed Oracle JDK8 64-bit and have setup the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable properly. When I run the command

```
java -v
```

it gives me the following error

```
Unrecognized option: -v
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have tried setting the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `-Xmx512M` and `-Xmx1024M` but that does not solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try  `java -version` instead

Comment: It doesn't means that your installation is bad, just that you used an unknown option, use `-verbose` for example (or `-version`)

Comment: @litelite thanks a lot. I kept trying -v and --version thinking that it had to be one of them. If you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has no `-v` option. Instead use `-version`